# What is wrong with the variance formula for linear regression betas in high dimension?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

According to linear regression formula, assumming the predictors are nonreandom, $$var[\hat{\beta}]=MSE *(X'X)^{-1}$$ where MSE is an unbiased estimator of the population variance.

Intuitively, when the number of predictors (p + 1) is greater than the number of data, the regression model is overfitting the data. Because of overfitting, one would expect the variance of $\hat{\beta}$ to be **big**.

However, according to the formula, because MSE = 0, we have $$var[\hat{\beta}]=MSE *(X'X)^{-1} = 0$$

What goes wrong? There must be some implicit assumption with this formula that failed in this scenarios.

Comment: @whuber This is not a duplicate. I modified the question so that p+1 > n and the denominator is zero . The MSE estimate gets negative. PLease lift the hold.